# Get Role by name (discord.py Rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem with my Discord Bot. I want to create a text channel with read permissions for a Supporter Role, but I don't want to use the `role_id`. So, I tried to use the following code, but I can't create any channel.

```
          supporter_role = discord.utils.get("Supporter")
            overwrites = {
            supporter_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True), guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False), author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
          }
          channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name='║Ticket - {}'.format(authorname), overwrites=overwrites)
```

Answer (score 7):

The function discord.utils.get takes an iterable and searches for a matching item in the iterable. Since you haven't specified the iterable, the get function doesn't really know where to match the given name.

Hence you'll have to specify `guild.roles` as the first argument.

```
discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name="Supporter")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

How to get a Role by Name

```
Mod = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Mods")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).