# How to check whether someone has a certain role in a certain server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to check whether someone has a role however in the on message function I can not pass in anything else other than message or else it will not work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 print("Test Success")
 msg = message.content
 member = message.author.id
 print(message.author.id)
 if message.author == client.user:
    return  # Do not check the bots messages
 
 if "" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('Shut The Fuck Up', mention_author=True)
        return
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `discord.py check user roles` into a search engine? What happened when you tried looking for the documentation directly, and then searching within the documentation for the relevant part? Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question isn't clear, I'm assuming you want to do something if the author has a role.

```py
async def on_message(message):
   #other stuff
   role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='RoleName')
   if role in message.author.roles:
       # do stuff
       await message.channel.send('You have the role `RoleName`')
```

References:-

- [member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles)
- [Getting roles by role name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819810/get-role-by-name-discord-py-rewrite)